# How to convert MongoDB query to PHP that contains a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a query that works in MongoDB shell to convert String Date into readable dates. However, I dont know how to convert this query to PHP because it contains a function. How do I do it? Here's the query:

```
db.sample_collection.find().forEach(function (tweet){ db.sample_collection.update({_id: tweet._id}, {$set: {created_at: new Date(tweet.created_at)}});});
```

Here's what I've done so far

```
$collection->find()->forEach(function (tweet){ $collection->update(["_id"=> tweet->"_id"], ['$set'=> ["created_at"=> new Date(tweet->"created_at")]]);});
```

Comment: We're here to help, not to write code for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Twinfriends Hi! Oh I forgot to include my work so far. My bad. Here's what I've tried so far. 

`$collection->find()->forEach(function (tweet)[ "db.sample_collection"->update(["_id"=> "tweet._id"], ['$set'=> ["created_at"=> new Date("tweet.created_at")]]);]);`

Comment: There it's edited now haha

Comment: Name one language where this isn't a syntax error `function (tweet)[ "`

Comment: @baao im sorry but im new to programming. I've been through this for 3 days and still I couldnt figure out how to do it. That is why i've been seeking help.

Comment: Also I've read somewhere that you need to replace the "{}" to "[]" as well as ":" to "=>" and "." to "->" when transforming mongoDB queries to php.